# Slick doesn't run Evolutions with Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have an app that was using scala.play with a jdbc connection to a postgresql database and  play evolutions and I have been trying to migrate to using slick, to reduce the amount of boilerplate in the database client..

Following the docs for slick does not yeild results which is dissapointing.

here is what i have and what i get,
part of build.sbt

```scala
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.4.1"
libraryDependencies +="org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.7.26"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.4.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.6.0"

// Better field mappings for Postgres/Slick
libraryDependencies += "com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg" % "0.21.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg_circe-json" % "0.21.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "5.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "5.1.0"
```

application.conf

```
slick.dbs.app.profile="slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
slick.dbs.app.db.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app"
slick.dbs.app.db.user="app"
slick.dbs.app.db.password="password"
```

and a class

```
package com.cask.db

import com.google.inject.Inject
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
import java.sql.Timestamp
import scala.util.Random

class SlickDBClient @Inject()() extends UsersTable {
  val db = Database.forConfig("slick.dbs.app")

  def testAdd(): Unit ={
    val foo = UserTableRow(None,randomString,randomString,true,"2342","234234","234234",None,Some(12),new Timestamp(DateTime.now().getMillis()),new Timestamp(DateTime.now().getMillis()),None,"",None)
    db.run(addUsersQuery.insertOrUpdate(foo))
  }

  def randomString():String = {
    Iterator.continually(Random.nextPrintableChar()).filter(_.isLetterOrDigit).take(8).mkString
  }

  private lazy val addUsersQuery = users returning users.map(_.id) into (
    (f, id) => f.copy(id = Some(id))
  )
}
```

the cold compiles and runs but evolutions are not applied and testadd can be called without exception , but obviouslyt it isnt working as the evolutions are not being applied,, evolutions were being applied previously without slick just using play and jdbc

I have pushed it to github encase that helps
https://github.com/ArthurGibbs/scalaApp

incase anyone looks at the code DatabaseClient was the one i was previously using, using jdbc without slick,, i have set the default for di to use the mock one as i have has to remove some dependances that i have read i could not use at the same time as slick, SlickDBClient is called by an endpoint /api/users/testSlick

please help me understand where i am going wrong

EDIT, updated after some suggestions

```
[CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) [Guice/ErrorInCustomProvider]: RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app
  while locating ApplicationEvolutionsProvider
  at EvolutionsModule.<init>(EvolutionsModule.scala:23):
Binding(class ApplicationEvolutions to ProviderConstructionTarget(class ApplicationEvolutionsProvider) eagerly)
      \_ installed by: Modules$OverrideModule -> GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4
  while locating ApplicationEvolutions
```

Postgresql is version 14.5

Comment: The project doesn't compile. There are version conflicts when I try to execut `sbt run`. You would need to first fix that to get some help. Based on a quick look, I guess you would need to downgrade play to 2.8. You are using some libs that depends on scala-parser-combinators 2.3 and play use that version when the project runs on scala 3, but play slick pg is not compatible with scala 3 yet

Comment: ahh sorry, i added slick_pg,,  then did somthing else ,, i have pushed a fix the the build.sbt file

Answer (score 3):

first issue is that `play-slick-evolutions` is scoped for test in `build.sbt`. `% Test` must be removed from

```scala
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "5.1.0" % Test
```

the second problem is that you are using the `play jdbc datsources config` instead of `slick datasources config` in `application.conf`. Adding the following lines will make the evolutions module work

```
slick.dbs.app.profile="slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
slick.dbs.app.db.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app"
slick.dbs.app.db.user="app"
slick.dbs.app.db.password="password"
```

---

The article [Play Slick Migration Guide - Database configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.9.x/PlaySlickMigrationGuide#Database-configuration) helps to understand why your app is not running the evolution scripts

> With the past releases of Play Slick (which used Slick 2.1 or earlier), you used to configure Slick datasources exactly like you would configure Play JDBC datasources. This is no longer the case, and the following configuration will now be **ignored** by Play Slick:
>
> ```
> db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
> db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
> db.default.user=sa
> db.default.password=""
> ```
>
> Here is how you would need to migrate the above configuration:
>
> ```
> slick.dbs.default.profile="slick.jdbc.H2Profile$" # You must provide the > required Slick profile! 
> slick.dbs.default.db.driver=org.h2.Driver
> slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
> slick.dbs.default.db.user=sa
> slick.dbs.default.db.password=""
> ```